# Unable to launch a new activity.something to do with onAnimationEnd?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, listener, android-animation

Code for `QuizSplashActivity`:

```
package com.androidbook.triviaquiz;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String rest="First Time Launched";



        String launchd=DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
        String launcht=DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        String ldt=launchd+" "+launcht;

        SharedPreferences set=getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(set.contains("lastLaunch"))
        {rest=set.getString("lastLaunch", "default");

        }
        Log.i("LaunchInfo",rest);

        SharedPreferences.Editor edit=set.edit();

        edit.putString("lastLaunch",ldt);
        edit.commit();


        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        anime();
    }

    private void anime()
    {TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
    Animation f1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    t1.startAnimation(f1);
    TextView t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewBotTitle);
    Animation f2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);

    //t2.startAnimation(f2);
   // Animation fade2 =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
    //View.startAnimation(fade2);
    t2.startAnimation(f2);

    AnimationListener animListener=new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
            startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this,QuizMenuActivity.class));
            QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();

        }


        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }


    };
    f2.setAnimationListener(animListener);
    Animation spinin=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom_anim);
    LayoutAnimationController controller=new LayoutAnimationController(spinin);
    TableLayout tb=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    for(int i=0;i<tb.getChildCount();i++)
    {TableRow row=(TableRow) tb.getChildAt(i);
    row.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

    }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {super.onPause();
    TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
    t1.clearAnimation();
    TextView t2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewBotTitle);
    t2.clearAnimation();
    TableLayout tb=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    for(int i=0;i<tb.getChildCount();i++)
    {TableRow row=(TableRow) tb.getChildAt(i);
    row.clearAnimation();

    }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {super.onResume();
    anime();

    }


}
```

Code for QuizMenuActivity

```
package com.androidbook.triviaquiz;


import android.os.Bundle;

public class QuizMenuActivity extends QuizActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    }
}
```

After the animations in splash have played out (Specifically fade_in2) the `QuizMenuActivity` is supposed to be launched and splash finished. The Animations play out fine but the `QuizMenuActivity` doesn't seem to be launched. Playing around with the debugger/break points it seems the program flow never goes into `onAnimationEnd` (Animation animation) method. Though I might be wrong as I am pretty new with eclipse and android.

I've fixed the code based on the first reply and updated it.Now the listner is firing but after the start activity i get 'application has beenstopped unexpectedly.Please try again.Force Close'.Seems to be while in something called ZygoteInit$MethodAnd.

Is this the callstack:

```
tiv [Android Application]   
    DalvikVM[localhost:8612]    
        Thread [<3> main] (Running) 
        Thread [<13> Binder Thread #2] (Running)    
        Thread [<11> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

I think the callstacks supposed to be in the logcat but I'm getting 'Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied' error log in logcat.
Also the appliction seems to crash before the the animation f2(which is what is being listened for) has been displayed.t2 never gets displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-change manifest to this
-It solved my problem
-add dot in the beginning of activity name, not sure why or if it is necessary !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidbook.triviaquiz7"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/quizicon">
    <activity
        android:name=".QuizSplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuizGameActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuizSettingsActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuizScoresActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuizHelpActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuizMenuActivity"></activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are adding the animation listener to the 'fade2' animation object. But that animation is not set to any view like

```
view.startAnimation(fade2);
```

Without starting the animation for a view the listener will not fire.

Comment: Ok fixed that.Now the listner is firing but after the start activity i get 'application has beenstopped unexpectedly.Please try again.Force Close'.Seems to be while in something called ZygoteInit$MethodAnd.

Comment: Put ur stack trace up in the question. It will give an idea of what is causing the error.